# Different templates for UpdateView for the same model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

So I've got a template listing different products in user cart - I would like to give user a chance to update each product from this view. But depending on product type I would like to display different 'update_templates'.
What should be the best scenario for this situation?

Should I use few different UpdateViews for the same model? Like:

```
class ProductType1UpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = CartItem
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name_suffix = '_product1_update_form'

class ProductType2UpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = CartItem
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name_suffix = '_product2_update_form'
```

Or should I make it in one view, and add some if statements that will display proper template depending on product type? Like:

```
class ProductUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = CartItem
    fields = '__all__'
    {here if statement checking product id}
         template_name_suffix = '_product1_update_form'
    {elif}
         template_name_suffix = '_product2_update_form'
```

The first option works, but it doesn't feel right to me. How would I formulate my if statement to make it with the second option. Or is there maye another, better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override [**`get_template_names()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.template_name) function, like this:

```
class ProductUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = CartItem
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_template_names(self):
         if self.kwargs.get('id') == 1:
             self.template_name_suffix = '_product1_update_form'
          else:
             self.template_name_suffix = '_product2_update_form'
          return super(ProductUpdateView, self).get_template_names()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should override `get_tamplate_names` function.

```
class ProductUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = CartItem
    fields = '__all__'
    def get_template_names(self):
         if(condition):
              return '_product1_update_form'
         else:
              return '_product2_update_form'
```

Look at the flow of class view - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.template_name